# What's default field for query in solr

Tags: solr

I am a newcomer for solr, and i have a problem.

Every fieldType definition in managed-schema, you can specify both index analyzer and query analyzer, like this:

```
<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer type="index">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
  <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
  <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
  <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

So when i make a query like "q:something", how can i specify the field for "something", and what's the default field for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will find default search field in your [request handler](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/RequestHandlers+and+SearchComponents+in+SolrConfig), You need to check that in conf/solrconfig.xml

Check for "df" parameter,

```
<str name="df">_text_</str>
```

OR if you want to query particular field without changing df value then you need specify your query in below format,

```
fieldname:something
```

if your query has more than one token you can specify it as ,

```
fieldname:"something1 something2"
```

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Baloo do you know how to update the default field or fields in the queryHandler using the API.